# Falha na construção do projeto no netbeans

Tags: netbeans, jdbc

quando executo funciona normalmente porem quando aciono o limpar e construir ele apresenta esse erro:

```
warning: Supported source version 'RELEASE_6' from annotation processor 

'org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.CanonicalModelProcessor' less than -source '1.7'
Note: Creating static metadata factory ...
Note: Optional file was not found: META-INF/orm.xml continuing with generation.
Note: Optional file was not found: META-INF/eclipselink-orm.xml continuing with generation.
Note: Hibernate JPA 2 Static-Metamodel Generator 4.3.1.Final
error: Problem with Filer: Attempt to recreate a file for type br.com.unuead.solicita.dominio.entidade.Servidor_
error: Problem with Filer: Attempt to recreate a file for type br.com.unuead.solicita.dominio.entidade.ConfiguraInscricao_
error: Problem with Filer: Attempt to recreate a file for type br.com.unuead.solicita.dominio.entidade.Usuario_
3 errors
1 warning
```

Comment: Qual é a versão do Java que você está executando? No cmd: `java -version`.

Comment: 1.8.0_161, então fiz uma coisa aqui mas ainda estou com uma pulga atrás da orelha pois pesquisei um pouco e desativei no netbeans na propriedade compilação o checkbox "Ativar Processo de Anotações" isso resolveu ele limpou e construiu normalmente, porem isso pode afetar em algo no projeto ?